# Filter a list by a separated letters search term

Tags: java, android, arrays, search

I have some sort of a list like the example below which contains (Car & Racoon) words. If I want to search for "c r" I want it to return me "Car" not "Racoon". Below is my current approach but it doesn't consider the order of letters and returns me "Racoon" as well. I want a solution that is as flexible as possible for any spaces separated search terms/letters.

```
String[] words_list = {"Car", "Racoon"};
    String search_input = "c r";

    String[] input_parts = search_input.trim().toLowerCase().split(" ");

    for (String word : words_list){
        int matches= 0;
        for (String letter : input_parts) {
            if (word.toLowerCase().contains(letter)) {
                ++matches;
            }
        }

        if (matches == input_parts.length) {
            Log.d("Result : ", word);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good use case for Regular Expression.
Try something like this:

```
    String[] wordsList = {"Car", "Racoon"};
    String searchInput = "c r";

    String searchRegEx = searchInput.replace(" ", ".{1}");
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(searchRegEx, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    System.out.println("RegEx (case-insensitive) is: " + searchRegEx);

    for (String word : wordsList){
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(word);
        boolean match = matcher.matches();
        System.out.println("Test word '"+word + "' and match was: " + match);
    }
```

As you can see, I find each space and replace it with `.{1}` which means exactly once instance of any character. If you want to be open to matching one or more characters, you can use something like `.+` instead. Or you can be more specific and specify that only characters a-z upper and lower case should be matched: `[a-zA-Z]{1}` or `[a-zA-Z]+`. The `Pattern.CASE_INSENSTIVE` is important because otherwise your word list having a capital `C` for `Car` will not match the lowercase input.

In this case, compiling the Pattern is an important optimisation. As you know RegEx can be slow and if you in-line this in your for-loop, it will compile your regular expression for each test which will be slow and inefficient.

Comment: Thank you ! This is exactly what I was looking for. A one more question as I'm not experienced with regex. I've already used ".+" as it's more appropriate for my needs, but what if I want to match a sentence like "Car parking" with a regex like "C.+in" how can I make this also return true ? how can I make my space separated search terms return true whenever they lie within the words list ? Thanks.